# Boolean Simplification of A'B'C'+AB'C'+ABC'

Tags: boolean-algebra

My question is how do I reduce $\bar A\bar B\bar C+A\bar B\bar C+AB\bar C$ To get $(A+\bar B)\bar C$. I'm so lost just been trying to get it for awhile only using the 10 boolean simplification rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
A'B'C'+AB'C'+ABC'
C'(A'B'+AB'+AB)
C'(A'B'+A(B'+B))
C'(A'B'+A)
C'(B'+A)
```

It's that last step that used to trip me up.  `A'+AB = A'+B`  Forget what that law is called (identity?).

Comment: For some reason I just got stuck thank you very much.

Comment: @Hamster: the last one can be decomposed as `A'B'+A ≡ (A'+A)(B'+A) ≡ B'+A`, using the distributivity of disjunction over conjunction.

Answer (score 2):

```
A'B'C'+AB'C'+ABC'
=  B'C'+ABC'        by absorption [ A'B'C'+AB'C'  =  B'C' ]
=  AC'+B'C'         by absorption [ B'C'+ABC'  =  AC'+B'C' ]
=  (A+B')C'
```

Used tool at http://www.logicminimizer.com

Answer (score 0):

First use the distributive law to pull out the C', then work on the As and Bs

Answer (score 0):

A'B'C'+AB'C'+ABC'

=  B'C'+ABC'        according to absorption law [ A'B'C'+AB'C'  =  B'C' ]

=  AC'+B'C'         according to absorption law [ B'C'+ABC'  =  AC'+B'C' ]

=  (A+B')C'

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Check for similarities between terms.
2. Apply IDEMPOTENCY rule for letting you group 1 term with more.
3. Check to see if it is optimized or it can be more. Here you see C' which is a common factor.